# C++ Win32 get activated MDI szTitle

Tags: c++, winapi, title, mdi

I'm writing a notepad program in MS C++ 2010 Express with Win32. So far whenever the user opens or saves the document, it updates the status bar with the saved / opened filename. I also want to change the status bar to the current filename everytime a different MDI is activated. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your MDI child windows will get `WM_MDIACTIVATE` messages whenever their activation state changes - you then just have to pass that notification back to your top-level window in some way (via a custom message probably - you could even send the filename at the same time) to get it to update the status bar.

By the way, the MDI concept is more or less deprecated and Microsoft advise against using it in new applications:

> Many new and intermediate users find it difficult to learn to use MDI
>   applications. Therefore, you should consider other models for your
>   user interface. However, you can use MDI for applications which do not
>   easily fit into an existing model

For a notepad-type application the "modern" way to do this would be via a tabbed interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need.
Send WM_MDIGETACTIVE to the current client to ge the active client.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: But of course you would have moved on, but for anyone else asking the same question. Here is the answer i think.